# Spring Integration - How to aggregate errors from all splitters

Tags: spring-integration

I have a query around how to handle error scenarios in a best way when using Spring Integration.

Following is the usecase:

XML message

... some product related fields here

.
.

... some category related fields here

.
.
.

I am using splitters to split the message into different elements, e.g. Products and Categories being processed by separate splitters.

If there are any errors on a single product or category element, I want to continue to processing of other elements and then after complete processing of the message, I want to send an email to the end-user about the errors in the incoming message.

Please could you suggest the best way to implementation this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Your process should look like:

```
<splitter>
   <splitter>
   <aggregator>
<aggregator>
```

Each `<splitter>` should send its replies to the `ExecutorChannel` to proecess each item in parallel.

From other side before `<spliter> there is need``with` to handle downstrem exceptions.

Each `ExceptionHandler` should send a `compensation` message to the appropiate `<aggregator>` to have entire bunch of messages. Don't forget to `copyHeaders` from `failedMessage` to have `SequenceDetails` from `<splitter>` - it is necessary for `<aggregator>`.